# Select Tmux Window in Sessions List View

Tags: linux, tmux

Is there a way to select a Tmux Window by the number listed in the preview while in Sessions List view (activated with: `C-b s`)? In other words, how do I switch to window 3 (circled in red) in this screenshot?:

[image: Tmux in Sessions List View]

I am aware that I can switch windows directly (without going into Sessions List view) with: `C-b [1-0]`. The issue with that is that I often forget where my windows are and am helped by having a preview of their contents.

I am also aware that I can expand the windows in Sessions List view or else load the Window List view with: `C-b w` to see a list of all windows. The issue with that is that you have to spend time expanding the list of windows or (if you launch the Windows List view) you can only see a preview of one window at a time.

Edit: I attempted TechLoom's solution but it didn't work for me (see Gif)

[image: Attempting TechLoom's solution]

Answer (score 0):

After

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd>

The cursor should now be at the top of the session list.

To expand the session tree

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>+</kbd> or <kbd>right arrow</kbd>

Then when the tree expands displaying the number you can either press the corresponding number or use the arrow keys to select followed by enter to switch.

Comment: I attempted your solution but it didn't work for me (see Gif in edited question and note that I've remapped `Ctrl + b` to `Ctrl + Space` in my config).

When you enter the view with sessions as a list (`Ctrl + b s`) it doesn't seem like the previewed windows are treated as panes.

Comment: I got you, I thought this was panes, not sessions. Try this and see if this works for you. Ctrl + b s, then right arrow into the session (which expands the session into the windows), and then arrow down to the window you want and press enter.

Comment: Also after the session tree is expanded you can use the number in (...) and not have to arrow down to it and press enter. Just found out you don't need the arrow keys, just do 'Shift + +' (so that's the shift key and the plus key, that'll expand the tree and then just do the number inside (...) to jump to that session window. (This works with more than one session as well, just expand it again.) But not sure how to go back up without arrow keys.

Comment: Thanks @TechLoom! I was hoping that you could select one of the windows by the number on it (because that's where your eyes are when you're viewing the preview (and why else would the numbers be listed?)).

Expanding the sessions with `Shift++` (or simply opening the Sessions list view with `C-b w` in the first place) and then selecting a window with a number isn't too horrible, but it is annoying that the numbers in (...) don't correspond to the numbers on the window previews... 

Anyway, in conclusion, what I want to do doesn't appear possible but I appreciate the help!

Comment: I currently don't know of another way, but you are right the way in which TMUX is designed for panes should also work with sessions.